# TLS (Thread-Local-Storage) Callback support in Delphi 10 versions

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, thread-local-storage

I'm reading [this article](http://alexander-bagel.blogspot.com/2016/03/early-execution.html) that explain how to set a TLS callback in Delphi. The article author says the example works on "Delphi: 2007, 2010, XE4, XE10". But I have tested on Delphi 10 Seattle, Berlin, and Rio, and it does not work (the TLS callback is not executed), but when i test it on Delphi XE5, it works fine.

I also noted that the size of the `.map` file when compiling the **test_app** project in Delphi XE5 and Delphi 10 are different. The `.map` file in Delphi 10 is 5x bigger than the `.map` file in Delphi XE5 (something around 25KB and 125KB, respectively).

What detail am I missing here?

Following is the code with a reasonable translation to English of the **add_tls** project and the **test_app** project.

**PS:** The **test_app** project needs to be set to generate a `.map` file. Project > Options > Linking > Map file => Detailed.

add_tls:

```
program add_tls;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  SysUtils,
  Generics.Collections;

procedure ShowHelp;
begin
  Writeln('Usage: AddTls.exe "executable path"');
  Writeln('Return Codes:');
  Writeln('  - 0: TLS Callback successfully added');
  Writeln('  - 1: the path to the executable file is not specified');
  Writeln('  - 2: executable not found');
  Writeln('  - 3: MAP file not found matching the specified file');
  Writeln('  - 4: MAP file parsing error');
  Writeln('  - 5: error accessing executable file');
  Writeln('  - 6: there is no initialized TLS section in the executable file');
end;

type
  TSectionData = record
    Index: Integer;
    StartAddr: DWORD;
    SectionName: ShortString;
  end;
  TSectionDataList = TList<TSectionData>;

const
  HardcodeTLS32Offset = 12;

//
// This is an easy way to search for TLS BUT tables - only in projects,
// collected in XE and above
// If the executable is built by another compiler, it will not work naturally
// but the article is not about that :)
// so:
// =============================================================================
function GetTlsTableAddr(const FilePath: string): DWORD;
var
  F: TFileStream;
  DOS: TImageDosHeader;
  NT: TImageNtHeaders;
  I: Integer;
  Section: TImageSectionHeader;
begin
  Result := 0;
  // open the file for reading
  F := TFileStream.Create(FilePath, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    // read DOS header to go to NT
    F.ReadBuffer(DOS, SizeOf(TImageDosHeader));
    F.Position := DOS._lfanew;
    // We read the NT header to get the number of sections
    F.ReadBuffer(NT, SizeOf(TImageNtHeaders));
    // read sections and look for TLS
    for I := 0 to NT.FileHeader.NumberOfSections - 1 do
    begin
      F.ReadBuffer(Section, SizeOf(TImageSectionHeader));
      if PAnsiChar(@Section.Name[0]) = '.tls'  then
      begin
        // found IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY, we immediately correct the AddressOfCallback field
        Result := Section.PointerToRawData + HardcodeTLS32Offset;
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
end;

// just parse the map file and look for the addresses of the sections
function GetSectionDataList(const FilePath: string; var Index: Integer): TSectionDataList;
var
  S: TStringList;
  Line: string;
  Section: TSectionData;
begin
  Result := TSectionDataList.Create;
  try
    S := TStringList.Create;
    try
      S.LoadFromFile(FilePath);
      Index := 0;
      Writeln('I am looking for a table of sections...');
      while Copy(Trim(S[Index]), 1, 5) <> 'Start' do
        Inc(Index);
      Inc(Index);
      while Trim(S[Index]) <> '' do
      begin
        Line := Trim(S[Index]);
        Section.Index := StrToInt(Copy(Line, 1, 4));
        Delete(Line, 1, 5);
        Section.StartAddr := StrToInt('$' + Copy(Line, 1, 8));
        Delete(Line, 1, 19);
        Section.SectionName := ShortString(Trim(Copy(Line, 1, 8)));
        Result.Add(Section);
        Inc(Index);
      end;
      Writeln('Total sections found: ', Result.Count);
    finally
      S.Free;
    end;
  except
    // we suppress all exceptions. there are error codes
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln('GetSectionDataList: ' + E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

// again, parse the mapfile and look for the address of the function called tls_callback
// which (if found) we summarize with the address of the section in which it is located
function GetTlsCallbackAddr(const FilePath: string;
  SectionDataList: TSectionDataList; Index: Integer): DWORD;
var
  S: TStringList;
  Line: string;
  SectionIndex, TlsAddr: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  try
    S := TStringList.Create;
    try
      S.LoadFromFile(FilePath);
      Writeln('Looking for tls_callback...');
      repeat
        Line := Trim(S[Index]);
        Inc(Index);
        if Index = S.Count then Break;
      until Pos('.tls_callback', Line) <> 0;
      if Pos('.tls_callback', Line) = 0 then
      begin
        Writeln('No tls_callback entry found in MAP file');
        Exit;
      end;
      SectionIndex := StrToInt(Copy(Line, 1, 4));
      Delete(Line, 1, 5);
      TlsAddr := StrToInt('$' + Copy(Line, 1, 8));
      Writeln('tls_callback found, offset: ', IntToHex(TlsAddr, 8), ', section: ', SectionIndex);
      Writeln('Looking for a record about the section...');
      for Index := 0 to SectionDataList.Count - 1 do
        if SectionDataList[Index].Index = SectionIndex then
        begin
          Result := SectionDataList[Index].StartAddr + DWORD(TlsAddr);
          Writeln('TLS Callback, found in section "', SectionDataList[Index].SectionName,
            '", offset sections: ', IntToHex(SectionDataList[Index].StartAddr, 8),
            ', calculated addressc: ', IntToHex(Result, 8));
          Break;
        end;
      if Result = 0 then
        Writeln('Section containing tls_callback not found')
    finally
      S.Free;
    end;
  except
    // we suppress all exceptions. there are error codes
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln('GetTlsCallbackAddr: ' + E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

// directly patch file
function Patch(const FilePath, MapPath: string; TlsTable, CallbackAddr: DWORD): Boolean;
var
  F: TFileStream;
  NewFilePath, BackUpFilePath: string;
  OldCallbackTableAddr: DWORD;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    NewFilePath := ExtractFilePath(FilePath) + 'tls_aded_' +
      ExtractFileName(FilePath);
    Writeln('I create a copy of the file, the path: ', NewFilePath);
    CopyFile(PChar(FilePath), PChar(NewFilePath), False);
    F := TFileStream.Create(NewFilePath, fmOpenReadWrite);
    try
      Writeln('File open');
      F.Position := TlsTable;
      // read the address where the previous callback referred
      F.ReadBuffer(OldCallbackTableAddr, 4);
      // in a delphi image, it refers to the SizeOfZeroFill structure of IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY
      // in which both last fields are filled with zeros (supposedly there is no callback chain)
      // Therefore, we will not spoil the working structure and make it refer to the address
      // immediately outside of this structure (plus 2 yards in 32 bit, in 64 bit)
      Inc(OldCallbackTableAddr, SizeOf(DWORD) * 2);
      F.Position := TlsTable;
      // write a new address to the old place
      F.WriteBuffer(OldCallbackTableAddr, 4);
      Writeln('Assigned a new address to the chain of processors, offset: ', IntToHex(TlsTable, 8),
        ', new value: ', IntToHex(OldCallbackTableAddr, 8));
      // now we jump to the place where the VA address of the handler (not RVA) should be written
      // skip SizeOfZeroFill and Characteristics and get right behind them
      F.Position := TlsTable + SizeOf(DWORD) * 3;
      // and now write the address of our callback
      F.WriteBuffer(CallbackAddr, 4);
      Writeln('Callback address set, offset: ', IntToHex(TlsTable + SizeOf(DWORD) * 3, 8));
      // after which we write zero to indicate the end of the callback chain
      CallbackAddr := 0;
      F.WriteBuffer(CallbackAddr, 4);
    finally
      F.Free;
    end;
    // if everything is fine, then rename back
    Writeln('I create a backup');
    BackUpFilePath := FilePath + '.bak';
    DeleteFile(BackUpFilePath);
    RenameFile(FilePath, BackUpFilePath);
    Writeln('I keep the result');
    RenameFile(NewFilePath, FilePath);
    Writeln('All tasks completed');
    Result := True;
  except
    // we suppress all exceptions. there are error codes
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      // in the event of an error, we clean ourselves up - returning everything back
      DeleteFile(NewFilePath);
      RenameFile(BackUpFilePath, FilePath);
      Writeln('Patch: ' + E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  MapPath: string;
  TlsTable, CallbackAddr: DWORD;
  SectionDataList: TSectionDataList;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  ExitCode := 0;
  if ParamCount = 0 then
  begin
    ShowHelp;
    ExitCode := 1;
    ExitProcess(ExitCode);
  end;
  if not FileExists(ParamStr(1)) then
  begin
    Writeln('No executable found: ', ParamStr(1));
    ExitCode := 2;
    ExitProcess(ExitCode);
  end;
  TlsTable := GetTlsTableAddr(ParamStr(1));
  if TlsTable = 0 then
  begin
    ExitCode := 6;
    ExitProcess(ExitCode);
  end;
  MapPath := ChangeFileExt(ParamStr(1), '.map');
  if not FileExists(MapPath) then
  begin
    Writeln('MAP file not found: ', MapPath);
    ExitCode := 3;
    ExitProcess(ExitCode);
  end;
  Index := 0;
  SectionDataList := GetSectionDataList(MapPath, Index);
  try
    if SectionDataList.Count = 0 then
    begin
      Writeln('Could not build partition table');
      ExitCode := 9;
      ExitProcess(ExitCode);
    end;
    CallbackAddr := GetTlsCallbackAddr(MapPath, SectionDataList, Index);
    if CallbackAddr = 0 then
    begin
      ExitCode := 4;
      ExitProcess(ExitCode);
    end;
    if not Patch(ParamStr(1), MapPath, TlsTable, CallbackAddr) then
      ExitCode := 5;
  finally
    SectionDataList.Free;
  end;
  ExitProcess(ExitCode);
end.
```

test_app:

```
program test_app;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  Windows;

// this callback will be called if the file is correctly patched
procedure tls_callback(hModule: HMODULE;
  ul_reason_for_call: DWORD; lpReserved: Pointer); stdcall;
begin
  if ul_reason_for_call = DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH then
    MessageBox(0, 'TLS Callback Message', nil, 0);
end;

const
  ptls_callback: Pointer = @tls_callback;

begin
  // so that the tls_callback procedure appears in the MAP file
  // you need a link to it, it’s corny like this:
  if ptls_callback <> nil then
    MessageBox(0, 'Entry Point Message', nil, 0);
end.
```

Comment: Worth noting that there is no such thing as XE10. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Why the TLS Callback not is added to **test_app** when this last is compiled with D10 versions?  Here was tested D10 Seattle, Berlin, Rio, DXE7, DXE5; only on DXE5 worked.

Comment: What are you actually try to do though? I use TLS routinely, I've need seen any need for anything like this.

Comment: *`"I use TLS routinely, I've need seen any need for anything like this."`* I think that you not use this approach of article linked. You not undertood nothing here.

Comment: @BrowJr the linked article is not in English. I can't read it. Is a translation existing somewhere?

Comment: This is why it would be helpful if you could explain the problem you are trying to address with this hacky code. My instincts are that this is not the solution to your problem.

Comment: @fpiette, you can use [Google Chrome translator](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/2019-03-20_09h57_02.png) (set translate to English).

Comment: My guess would be to counter measure a possible debugger, as have been used by malware - prior to debuggers adapted (eg: [1](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/debugging-tls-callbacks/), [2](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=9)).

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Back in the day, malware writers didn't need SO

Answer (score -2):

If your aim is to have some code execute as soon as possible, here is something which works on any Delphi revision, and on any platform (not only Windows).

Create a small unit with no dependency (no `uses` clause at all).

```
unit FirstLoaded;

interface

// NO "uses" clause!

implementation

procedure SomeThingToDoEarly;
begin
end;

initialization
  SomeThingToDoEarly;
end.
```

Then put it as first unit in the `uses` clause of your project `.dpr` - before anything else.

```
program Project1;

uses
  FirstLoaded, // before anything!
  Forms,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

The code in the `initialization` part of your unit will be called just after `system.pas`.

Be aware that if you add something in your `uses` clause of your unit, those units (and their dependencies) would be initialized first.